# Return a response and redirect -- Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Iam working on a password reset API, which sends a mail to user with a link, which user need to click to reset password.
When the API is called it sends a success response.

But I also would like to redirect the URL to a page where user can set their new password.
I have successfully created the API to send mail and its giving success response as well, but i cant figure out how to redirect it.

It looks like the views could only return either a "Response" or "redirect".
Is there a way where both Response and Redirect co-exists in a single view. Please share me any docs or ideas if available for such.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `HttpResponseRedirect` by importing it from `django.http.response`